# converting integer to decimal with precision value

Tags: c#, winforms

how to make a text box to accept only decimal value with precision.

example.if the text box value is 12 .how to convert it to 12.00

and if it is 12.00 it must remain same..

thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean? `decimal.Parse(txtbox.Text);` will parse either number.  12.00 doesn't make any sense, 12 = 12.0 = 12.00 = 12.000 = ...  If you want to display it in a string with a defined precision, you should be able to go `number.ToString("#.000");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a [NumericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)-Control.

**Edit:** But to answer your question. To make `TextBox`-Control only accept numeric values, you'd have to suppress every key you do not want, and after that convert the input into a `Decimal`.

```
Decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(this.yourTextBox.Text);
```

Or the fail-safe way:

```
Decimal value = 0;
String toParse = this.yourTextBox.Text;

if(!Decimal.TryParse(toParse, out value) {
    // The user managed to break it...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple, fixed width variant is:

```
textBox1.Text = String.Format("{0,12:0.00}", textBox1.Text);
```

- 0 = first value (in this case
  textBox1.Text)
- 12 = minimal width
- 0.00 = decimal (i.e. you could use #) find out more variants with
  String.Format on msdn

Answer (score 1):

Add an Event to the TextBoxChanged:

```
public void On_textbox1TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Double dblVal = 0;
   if(Double.TryParse(this.textbox1.Text, ref dblVal))
   {
      this.textbox1.Text = dblVal.ToString("N2"); // Prints two 2 decimal places
   }
   else { /* Handle invalid value */ }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do a combination of the above on text change, and string formatting, but also go with a MASKED textbox.  That will allow you to put in an expected mask to allow too.